# How can I implicitly compare 2 objects with the same member variables?

Tags: c++

X is a type of calendar object (Gregorian, Julian, Islamic, etc).

I am creating a library to operate and compare different lunar calendars. I have a Julian Day class that allows me to convert any calendar date to a Julian Day Number. The issue I am having is when I try to compare (specifically ==) a Gregorian (calendar) object with an X (calendar) object it always tries to compare Gregorian.to_string() with x.to_julian_day(). How am I able to achieve a comparison where it will evaluate lhs.to_julian_day() with rhs.to_julian_day.

In each calendar class I have specified a constructor from a Julian Day object, which to my knowledge should specify and implicit conversion from X Calendar object to a Julian Day object. On top of this I have provided an operator to implicitly cast an X calendar object to a Julian Day Object. I have also included an assignment operator to assign an X calendar object from a Julian Day object.

To compare the objects I included all 6 relational operator overloads in my Julian Day class.

I have tried creating operator overloads on the "==" operator, but this results in the compiler nor knowing what operator to use (overloads have similar conversions C2666).

Julian Day Class

```cpp
class Jd {
    jd_t    jd_;
public:
    Jd();

    /** Constructor from real number. */
    constexpr Jd(jd_t jd) : jd_(jd) {}

    /** Constructor from a Now Type */
    Jd(now_t const& bTime);

    /** Get the number of days. */
    constexpr jd_t jd() const { return jd_; }

    std::string to_string() const;

};

inline bool operator == (Jd const& lhs, Jd const& rhs) { return lhs.jd() == rhs.jd(); }
inline bool operator != (Jd const& lhs, Jd const& rhs) { return lhs.jd() != rhs.jd(); }
inline bool operator <= (Jd const& lhs, Jd const& rhs) { return lhs.jd() <= rhs.jd(); }
inline bool operator >= (Jd const& lhs, Jd const& rhs) { return lhs.jd() >= rhs.jd(); }
inline bool operator <  (Jd const& lhs, Jd const& rhs) { return lhs.jd() < rhs.jd(); }
inline bool operator >  (Jd const& lhs, Jd const& rhs) { return lhs.jd() > rhs.jd(); }
```

Gregorian Class

```cpp
class Gregorian {
        year_t      year_ = 1;
        month_t     month_ = 1;
        day_t       day_ = 1;
        hour_t      hour_ = 0;
        minute_t    min_ = 0;
        second_t    sec_ = 0;

        void from_jd(jd_t jd) { jd_to_gregorian(jd, year_, month_, day_, hour_, min_, sec_); }
        jd_t to_jd() const { return gregorian_to_jd(year_, month_, day_, hour_, min_, sec_); }
    public:
        Gregorian();

        Gregorian(Jd const& jd) { from_jd(jd.jd()); }

        std::string to_string() const;

        //Implicit cast to Jd class. */
        operator Jd () const { return Jd(to_jd()); }


        //Assign and convert from Jd type to Gregorian type. 
        Gregorian& operator = (Jd const& jd) {
            from_jd(jd.jd());
            return *this;
        }
    };
```

Islamic Class

```cpp
class Islamic {
        year_t year_ = 1;
        month_t month_ = 1;
        day_t day_ = 1;
        hour_t hour_ = 0;
        minute_t min_ = 0;
        second_t sec_ = 0;
    public:
        // Default constructor
        Islamic();

        /** Construct a Islamic date from Julian Day Number object.
            @param jd [in] Jd object.
            */
        Islamic(Jd const& jd) { jd_to_islamic(jd.jd(), year_, month_, day_, hour_, min_, sec_); }


        std::string to_string() const;

        /** Implicit cast to Jd class. */
        operator Jd () const { return Jd(islamic_to_jd(year_, month_, day_, hour_, min_, sec_)); }

        /** Assign and convert from Jd type to Islamic type. */
        Islamic& operator = (Jd const& jd) {
            jd_to_islamic(jd.jd(), year_, month_, day_, hour_, min_, sec_);
            return *this;
        }
    };
```

With the given classes above we would be comparing a Gregorian object to an Islamic object.

The testing is being conducted with BOOST. We can assume that localDateTime is our Gregorian object and now is our Islamic object. We can also assume that localDateTime and now are being initialized to the exact same thing.

The following BOOST test always fails: 
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(localDateTime, now);

The results of this test are: "check localDateTime == now has failed [Saturday, October 12 2019 CE, 3:04:36 pm != JD 2.66383e+06]"

We can see that it's trying to compare a string with a Jd object. Why is this happening?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please try to create a simple [mcve] to show us, and include an exact, full and complete copy-paste of the errors the compilers are giving.

Comment: This is way too much code. Cut it down to a ~20 line example of the problem, including your test case that is failing.